# "He is a better something" or "He is a better of something"

Tags: word-usage

I'm wondering which sentence is correct or more correct.

1. These indicate that he might be a better of an athlete than you are.
2. These indicate that he might be a better an athlete than you are.

Or just simply

3. These indicate that he might be a better athlete than you are.

Or are there any better ways to phrase it?

Answer (score 1):

The correct sentence here is option 3.

"Better" in this context is an adjective; one that is describing the noun "athlete" in this sentence.

In the same way that you would say "a red ball", and not "a red a ball", you would also say "a better athlete", not "a better an athlete".